# Error with labels in the training step: InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Label IDs must >= 0]

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, tensorflow, input

I am new to Tensorflow and I hope I get some help here, I'm trying to make a neural network which gets four inputs and one output, it looks like a simple task in Tensorflow but I'm still get this error:

> InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Label IDs must >= 0]
>   [Condition x >= 0 did not hold element-wise:] [x (dnn/head/ToFloat:0)
>   = ] [[0][0][0]...]     [[Node: dnn/head/assert_range/assert_non_negative/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert = Assert[T=[DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT], summarize=3, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](dnn/head/assert_range/assert_non_negative/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch,
>   dnn/head/assert_range/assert_non_negative/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_0,
>   dnn/head/assert_range/assert_non_negative/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_1,
>   dnn/head/assert_range/assert_non_negative/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_2,
>   dnn/head/assert_range/assert_non_negative/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_1)]]

This is my code, thanks in advance.

```
F1 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('F1')
F2 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('F2')
F3 =tf.feature_column.numeric_column('F3')
F4 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('F4')
F5 =tf.feature_column.numeric_column('F5')
F6 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('F6')
F7  = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('F7')
F8 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('F8')
F9 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('F9')
F10  = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('F10')
F11 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('F11')
F12  = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('F12')
F13 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('F13')

deep_columns = [F2, F6, F11,F5]


COLUMNS = ["F1", "F2", "F3", 
"F4", "F5", "F6", "F7", 
"F8", "F9", "F10", "F11",  
"F12"]

df_train = pd.read_csv("C:/data_4.csv", 
names=COLUMNS, sep = "\t",skiprows=1,skipinitialspace=True)
df_train = df_train.fillna(0)
Xtrain = df_train.drop("F7", axis=1)  
y_train = pd.DataFrame(df_train.F7)
ytrain['F7'] = df_train.F7
ytrain = ytrain.astype(int) 

estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
 feature_columns=deep_columns,
 hidden_units=[7, 10, 20])

inp = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(Xtrain,ytrain, 
    batch_size= 128,
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=True,
    queue_capacity=1000,
    num_threads=1,
    target_column='F7')

estimator.train(input_fn=inp,steps=200)
```

Comment: Check your F7 data column since it contains negative values. The error is pretty clear!